# Issue a warning when casting a nullable type to the corresponding primitive type instead of using the Value property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, casting, warnings, nullable

I'd like to prevent myself from falling into the following pit:

```
int? data = null;
... 
... 
int result = (int)data;
```

The above code compiles with no error and no warning, and will result in a `Nullable object must have a value` exception in case `data` is null.

Is there a warning we can turn on Visual Studio (Community/Professional/Code) to not allow this kind of explicit cast, essentially forcing the usage of `Value` property? This way, I think there are higher chances one would not miss the null check.

Comment: I suggest ReSharper :)

Comment: I know its possible to make an FxCop rule that detects this.

Comment: @mjwills, the way I see it, using `.Value` (and in general, accessing a property) is a strong trigger for a pavlovian reaction we have as developers, to do a null check.

Comment: Would it be possible to build your own StyleCop Analyzers rule to enforce this?

Comment: @mjwills, I rather a static code analysis solution. Actually, when using VS2017 (which is not always the case for me), I tend to disable Roslyn Analyzers so they don't crash Visual Studio.

Comment: @mjwills, please, post a StyleCop solution. No one else has suggested an alternative, so I guess I'd have to go with that.

Comment: I haven't _written_ one. I was more suggesting you having a go at writing one yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with C# 8:

Add the pragma `#nullable enable` anywhere in the source file, or apply it to the whole project ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types#create-the-application-and-enable-nullable-reference-types)). You'll get a warning saying `Nullable value type may be null`.